# How to count a character

Tags: ruby

I need to count the number of peaches and eggplants in a string and say which appears more. I tried this:

```
def counting(eggplant_peaches)
  eggplants_counting = 0
  peaches_counting = 0
  (0..eggplant_peaches.length).each do |i|
    if eggplant_peaches[i] == 
      eggplants_counting = eggplants_counting + 1
    elsif eggplant_peaches[i] == 
      peaches_counting = peaches_counting + 1
    end
  end
  if eggplants_counting > peaches_counting
    puts “More ”
  elsif peaches_counting > eggplants_counting
    puts “More ”
  end
end
```

I get an error:

```
undefined local variable or method '' for main:Object
```

How can I count and make my code littler [sic]?

Comment: You missing some quotes: `eggplant_peaches[i] == ''` or `eggplant_peaches[i] == ""`. And you'll want to use the right quotes in `puts` calls: `puts 'More '` or `puts "More "`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your eggplants and peaches need to be enclosed in quotes to be proper strings,

```
if eggplant_peaches[i] == ""
```

Now as you asked how to make your code shorter, you could do this:

```
def counting(array)
  winner = array.group_by(&:itself).sort_by {|k,v| v.size }.last.first
  # The steps here are:
  # %w[  ].group_by(&:itself)
  #  => {""=>[""], ""=>["", ""]}
  # .sort_by { |k,v| v.size}
  #  => [["", [""]], ["", ["", ""]]]
  # .last
  #  => ["", ["", ""]]
  # .first
  #  => ""
  puts "More #{winner}"
end

counting(%w[  ])
 => More
```

As a bonus, the above code also works for bananas:

```
counting(%w[     ])
 => More
```

Comment: I love my bananas 

Answer (score 3):

a bit faster approach (frequency counting):

```
array.each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |i, res|
  res[i] += 1
end.max_by(&:last).first
```

though you can also make it fast enough using :max_by in [Marcin Kołodziej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6603195/marcin-ko%C5%82odziej)'s decision:

```
array.group_by(&:itself)
     .max_by { |k, v| v.size }
     .first
```

Comment: Using `max_by` is definitely nicer than sorting, but it won't work in the second example, it should be `max_by { |k,v| v.size }`.